# Jumblr create Photoset post

Tags: java, tumblr

I'm using the [jumblr][1] API wrapper for java. Now I want to add a Photo to a PhotoPost like that:

```
PhotoPost pp = client.newPost(blogName, PhotoPost.class);
pp.isPhotoSet(true);
List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();

Photo photo = new Photo();
photo.setSource("http://example.com/a.jpg");

Photo photo2 = new Photo();
photo.setSource("http://example.com/b.jpg");

photos.add(photo);
photos.add(photo2);

pp.setPhotos(photos);
pp.save();
```

My Problems currently are:

- how to set the URL in a Photo Object
- how to set the Photos[] array in a PhotoPost

Has anyone an idea on that?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Jumblr doesn't support photosets, but if you request the feature at https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr I'd be happy to add it